# How to program Crystal report to lookup a record in a table

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a table with fields:

- Material Number
- Order Code
- Supplier Code
- Description

I have a Crystal Reports rpt file that I manually enter all the information to generate labels.

I am trying to program this using the built in formula editor, so when I enter the *Material Number* (which is a unique code) it will automatically display other 3 relevant fields.

I have tried few formulas in the formula editor without any luck.

[image: Crystal Report Formula Editor]

Can anyone help?

relliK

UPDATE: I have added the table for clarification:

[image: Spares List - Table]

I simply want a label printed with only one user input being the Material Number, and then the code/formula in crystal reports to fetch the other data based on the Material number and produce the label.

Thank you for you interest in this issue.

UPDATE 2: I have added a sample label, I would only want to enter 20506871 as Material and the other data fields to be pulled from Excel.

[image: Sample Label]

Not sure if I can use parameter fields and/or I would like some help on programming the parameter fields.

Comment: Couldn't understand what exactly displaying other 3 fields can you show design

Comment: @Siva i have updated the question, includes an image of the data table.

Comment: ok are you trying to display fields in report? or you want data to be added to parameters because in your code you are assigning data to parameters

Comment: i want to display relevant field for a record, i was trying to use parameters to do this

Comment: ok I understood you need to use dynamic cascading prompts in parameter fields.. try that feature which exactly does what youi require